Composer could not find the config file: C:\... . To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file
Don't be agressive, I'm begginer on php. I have tried to run composer require symfonycasts/verify-email-bundle, but i had error Composer could not find the config file: C:\... . To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file..
My composer.json:
{
    "name": "symfony/website-skeleton",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "MIT",
    "description": "A skeleton to start a new Symfony website",
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "require": {
        "php": ">=8.1",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "doctrine/annotations": "*",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.12",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.3",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.11",
        "phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock": "^5.4",
        "phpstan/phpdoc-parser": "^1.29",
        "symfony/asset": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/console": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/doctrine-messenger": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/expression-language": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^2",
        "symfony/form": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/http-client": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/intl": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/mailer": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/mime": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.0",
        "symfony/notifier": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/process": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/property-access": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/property-info": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/runtime": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/serializer": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/string": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/translation": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/validator": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/web-link": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "6.1.*",
        "symfonycasts/verify-email-bundle": "^1.17",
        "twig/extra-bundle": "^2.12|^3.0",
        "twig/twig": "^2.12|^3.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5",
        "symfony/browser-kit": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/css-selector": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/debug-bundle": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.0",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^7.0",
        "symfony/stopwatch": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "6.1.*"
    },
    "config": {
        "allow-plugins": {
            "composer/package-versions-deprecated": true,
            "symfony/flex": true,
            "symfony/runtime": true
        },
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php72": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php73": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php74": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php80": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php81": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*",
        "doctrine/orm": "2.12.0"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "6.1.*"
        }
    }
}


I write here cause i don't know why can't I fix that:

I have composer.json in my project and in the folder composer.
I have Composer version 2.7.4 2024-04-22 21:17:03 and PHP version 8.3.6 (C:\php7\php.exe)
Php and Composer created in system environment variables and user's environment variables
Im cmd if I write composer show i have  Composer could not find the config file: C:\composer(BUT MY COMPOSER.JSON IS IN Composer FOLDER :( ) To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file.


"in the folder composer" Are you running this from inside that folder? Actually, why do you even have a folder "composer"? You run these commands from your project folder, where your composer.json is, right?

What command are you entering to try and run this?

@brombeer yes, but I have Composer could not find the config file: C:\composer. Idk why cause i have composer.json in C:\composer

you are running the command from the wrong directory. change into the project directory root (where the composer.json file is) and run your require command there.

@OldBoy For the first time i'm entering on phpstormcomposer require symfonycasts/verify-email-bundle and got Cannot run program "composer" (in directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\php-project"): CreateProcess error=2, Cannot find the specified file

@OldBoy And then i cheked the performance via cmd composer show and got Composer could not find the config file: C:\composer To initialize a project, please create a composer.json

First it "Cannot run program "composer"" but then it can? Re-read https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-windows to make sure the composer executable is installed correct. From any path you should be able to run composer. Change to your project folder, run composer require symfonycasts/verify-email-bundle
